# Magento 2 - How to Override Checkout LayoutProcessor

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, onepage-checkout

I wanted to customize a private method of

> \Block\Checkout\Layoutprocessor.php

```
private function getAddressAttributes()
{
    // My code here
}
```

To do that I have created a custom module and did with **di.xml**. Now issue is if I copy COMPLETE code of core **`"\Block\Checkout\Layoutprocessor.php"`** file into my module **`"\Block\Checkout\Layoutprocessor.php"`** it works fine, but if I remove all other methods and just leave desired method (where I have made changes) it doesn't work.

So I need help how I can customize layout processor individual method instead of copying complete file code and make my changes :

Here is my code :

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" />
</config>
```

**LayoutProcessor.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger;

class LayoutProcessor extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeMetadataDataProvider
 */
private $attributeMetadataDataProvider;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\AttributeMapper
 */
protected $attributeMapper;

/**
 * @var AttributeMerger
 */
protected $merger;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Options
 */
private $options;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeMetadataDataProvider $attributeMetadataDataProvider
 * @param \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\AttributeMapper $attributeMapper
 * @param AttributeMerger $merger
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeMetadataDataProvider $attributeMetadataDataProvider,
    \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\AttributeMapper $attributeMapper,
    AttributeMerger $merger
) {
    $this->attributeMetadataDataProvider = $attributeMetadataDataProvider;
    $this->attributeMapper = $attributeMapper;
    $this->merger = $merger;
}

/**
 * @deprecated
 * @return \Magento\Customer\Model\Options
 */
private function getOptions()
{
   // Core method code
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
private function getAddressAttributes()
{
   /* my custom code will go here */
}

/**
 * Convert elements(like prefix and suffix) from inputs to selects when necessary
 *
 * @param array $elements address attributes
 * @param array $attributesToConvert fields and their callbacks
 * @return array
 */
private function convertElementsToSelect($elements, $attributesToConvert)
{
    // Core method code
}

/**
 * Process js Layout of block
 *
 * @param array $jsLayout
 * @return array
 */
public function process($jsLayout)
{
    // Core method code
}

/**
 * Inject billing address component into every payment component
 *
 * @param array $configuration list of payment components
 * @param array $elements attributes that must be displayed in address form
 * @return array
 */
private function processPaymentConfiguration(array &$configuration, array $elements)
{
    // Core method code
}
}
```

Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use Plugin as well.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR :** If the class you are using preference against has private methods you have to copy them , the whole point of private methods is that only the declaring class can call them, thats why you class cannot call the private methods of class you extended

If you override a class using preference **you have to use the original code entirely where there may be private functions** etc and add your modification to it (**the whole point of private methods is that only the declaring class can call them.**), as when you use preference your class is called instead of the class you have overridden.

You can read more about preference from Alan storm's blog - [here](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_preferences/).

Following is a part which explains this ;

> If you take a look at di.xml, you’ll see the following “top level”
>   (under the real top level , that is) node.
>
> ```
> type="Pulsestorm\TutorialObjectPreference\Model\English" /> This is the configuration node where we can set a class preference. In
> ```
>
> plain english, we’re telling the object manager that
>
> When someone asks you to instantiate a
>   Pulsestorm\TutorialObjectPreference\Model\MessageHolderInterface (the
>   for attribute) you should actually instantiate a
>   Pulsestorm\TutorialObjectPreference\Model\English object (the type
>   attribute)

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is basically because you have been using private parent methods in your own class, so you need a copy of your own for private methods. I have done something similar by creating overriding block class as below:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger;

class LayoutProcessor extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeMetadataDataProvider
 */
private $attributeMetadataDataProvider;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\AttributeMapper
 */
private $options;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeMetadataDataProvider $attributeMetadataDataProvider
 * @param \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\AttributeMapper $attributeMapper
 * @param AttributeMerger $merger
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeMetadataDataProvider $attributeMetadataDataProvider,
    \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\AttributeMapper $attributeMapper,
    AttributeMerger $merger
) {
    $this->attributeMetadataDataProvider = $attributeMetadataDataProvider;

    parent::__construct($this->attributeMetadataDataProvider,
    $attributeMapper, $merger)
}

/**
 * @deprecated
 * @return \Magento\Customer\Model\Options
 */
private function getOptions()
{
   // Core method code
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
private function getAddressAttributes()
{
   /* my custom code will go here */
}

/**
 * Convert elements(like prefix and suffix) from inputs to selects when necessary
 *
 * @param array $elements address attributes
 * @param array $attributesToConvert fields and their callbacks
 * @return array
 */
private function convertElementsToSelect($elements, $attributesToConvert)
{
    // Core method code
}

/**
 * Inject billing address component into every payment component
 *
 * @param array $configuration list of payment components
 * @param array $elements attributes that must be displayed in address form
 * @return array
 */
private function processPaymentConfiguration(array &$configuration, array $elements)
{
    // Core method code
}
}
```

Comment: I am not getting any error, my code works fine. The only concern i have is to override a single method i need to copy all code of core Layoutprocessor.php file into my module layout processor. which i don't want. Secondly you have missed one public  function "process" in your code sample it will not work and through error "implement the remaining methods (Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface::process"

Comment: Thanks but I did not need to write the public methods.